# extjs grid posting data rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, grid

i am trying to post Ext JS Grid data into database...Is there any tutorial to guide me to post the whole grid to the server?? plz help..

Comment: Is it an editable grid? otherwise why do you want to post grid to database?

Comment: what i want to do is i have form wherein i insert details that in turn gets added to grid..when all the record have been inserted in the grid,i want to post all the records at a time into the database...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looping through the store for your grid and adding data into array or object and then post it with ajax.

You can get the data like this:

```
var resultArray = [];

for (var i=0; i < yourGridObject.store.data.items.length; i++)
{
     resultArray.push(this.store.data.items[i].data.columnName1);
}
```

Then post with ajax

```
var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
conn.request({
    url: 'foo.php',    
    method: 'POST',
    success: successCallBack,   
    failure: failureCallback,
    params: { gridData: resultArray.join(',') }  
});
```

Comment: thanx dasha..i dnt want to use array..is there any other way??

Comment: hey can any1 plzz tell me how to submit ExtJS form?? I want to submit form data to JSON store...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is not so hard (the one I did).

Suppose you have a model and want the grid items to be part of this model.

1 Make sure the model has proxy of type "**ajax**" (not rest)

2 Use the following writer in this proxy

```
   writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
        encode: false,
        writeAllFields: true,
        listful: true,
        root: 'data' //optional
})
```

3 Iterate over the grid to create an array

```
var itemsArr = [];
myGrid.each(function( record ){
    itemsArr.push( record.data );
});
```

4 Create a instance of the model and link the grid items

```
var model = Ext.ModelManager.create({
    Name        : 'Deckard Cain',
    Address     : 'Tristram',
    myItems     : itemsArr //The model contains this item (since hasMany don't work for nested store writer submit)
}, 'MyModel');
```

5 Save it (using the model instance)

```
model.save(); 
// This will send to the server an ajax request {"data":{"Name":"Deckard Cain","Address":"Tristram","myItems":[{"gridId":1,"gridItemName":"name2"},{"gridId":2,"gridItemName":"name2"}]}}
```

I posted this solution also at:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?124362-Nested-loading-nested-saving-in-new-data-package